GeoListPlot Coloring Points (again) PlotStyle vs. PlotMarkers
This problem has been address before, but for some reason the proposed answers do not work with my data running on Vers. 14.1 on Windows 11/64 bit.  I am at a loss to identify how to properly set the options to control the color and size of plotted points with PlotStyle or the shape with PlotMarkers.
The following code illustrates the problem.  I seek to control the color, size, and shape of the data points.
Data:
lat0 = FromDMS["29°9'0\"N"] // N; long0 = FromDMS["88°33'0,\"W"] // N;
lat1 = FromDMS["25°35'0\"N"] // N; long1 = FromDMS["83°42'0\"W"] // N;
lat2 = FromDMS["25°35'0\"N"] // N; long2 = FromDMS["83°42'0\"W"] // N;
lat3 = FromDMS["29°41'0\"N"] // N; long3 = FromDMS["59°47'0\"W"] // N;
lat4 = FromDMS["29°15'0\"N"] // N; long4 = FromDMS["88°11'0\"W"] // N;
lat5 = FromDMS["27°59'24\"N"] // N; long5 =  FromDMS["92°55'35\"W"] // N;
lat6 = FromDMS["28°59'52.28\"N"] // N; long6 =  FromDMS[" 89° 4'5.74\"W"] // N;
lat7 = FromDMS["29°30'0\"N"] // N; long7 = FromDMS["85°36'0\"W"] // N;
lat8 = FromDMS["15°030'0\"N"] // N; long8 =  FromDMS["63°50'0\"W"] // N;

Plot 1 generates the default settings for data points of one color (default = Red but changed to White with a default Square).
plot1 = GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat0, long0}], 
GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotMarkers -> {White, Small}
]

Plot 2 generates the setting for a point (a different species, but with PlotMarkers option changed to Yellow).
plot2 = GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[{lat8, long8}], 
GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotMarkers -> {Yellow, Small}]

Using Show, I merge both plots into one as desired.
Show[plot1, plot2, GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}]

However, I would prefer to be able to specify the shape of the plot marker to a small circle, triangle or other marker with control over color and size similar to the default or open small circles.  Numerous species need to be plotted, but not shown in this example so control of multiple shapes, colors, and sizes necessary, as is controlling their size depending on map scale (GeoRange).  I can change the size with Small to make the points small or Tiny to make them tiny, however, it would be better to be able to control their absolute/or absolute-relative size to the GeoRange (some maps will have many points so smaller, but more visible yet of discernable shape is desirable).  With PlotMarkers -> I can not seem to create a small disk or torus of selectable size, just a square, which seems to be the default.
I try various suggested approaches to changing the options PlotStyle and PlotMarkers in the following plots, none of which generate any errors, just not what is wanted. It would appear that PlotMarkers is the more general option to specify, but I can't figure out how to specify a change of shape (ie Disk[] included in the option, prints Disk[] rather than a disk, which I can then give a diameter, presumably centered on the center of the disk.
Plot 3 - the default without specifying options point in Red.
plot3 = GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], 
GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], 
GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], 
GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, 
GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]

Plot 4 - using PlotStyle -> {Yellow} (NB as a list, but does not override default and thus points still in Red).
plot4 = GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat0, long0}], 
GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotStyle -> {Yellow}]

Plot 5 - using PlotStyle -> Yellow (NB as a "naked" option not a list, but does not override default and thus points in Red.
plot5 = GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat0, long0}], 
GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotStyle -> Yellow]

Plot6 - using PlotStyle -> {Directive[Small, Yellow] attempting to control individual points but again no override of default Red making them smaller and yellow.
plot6 = GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], 
GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Small, Yellow], Directive[Small, Yelow], 
Directive[Small, Yellow], Directive[Small, Yellow], 
Directive[Small, Yellow], Directive[Small, Yellow], 
Directive[Small, Yellow]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]

How can one control their shape, color and size of the plotted "points", either with PlotStyle or PlotMarker?

For me it is also unclear how to do this. I have played a bit one option is to input your coordinates as separate lists i.e GeoListPlot[{{list1},{list2}},PlotStyle->{Green,Red}], not too sure how to then play with different shapes and sizes

The only workaround I could find would be to overlay a ListPlot on top of your map? Not ideal but then you have the flexibility to play with symbols the way you want.

The PlotMarkers option sets the shape, size and color of plotted points. PlotStyle is not the solution for points as it applies to polygons for countries, cities, etc.
PlotMarkers accepts graphics objects or styled text. With graphics objects, set colors and size as with any Graphics option. Use Style and its options with characters or text. Here are some examples.
(* yellow points scaled to the size of the image *)
GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat0, long0}],
  GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[{0,0}, Scaled[0.025]]}]]


(* white stars scaled to the image size *)
GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[{lat0, long0}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat1, long1}], GeoPosition[{lat2, long2}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat3, long3}], GeoPosition[{lat4, long4}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat5, long5}], GeoPosition[{lat6, long6}], 
  GeoPosition[{lat7, long7}]}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", 
GeoRange -> {{10, 50}, {-100, -50}}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", 
PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FivePointedStar]", White, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]]



The trick is to encapsulate the wanted Plotmarkers in a graphic and then control it.  Too bad that isn't readily apparent in the documentation.  Your answer explains why Plotstyle printed the text for the option rather than executing it.  Thanks this clarifies my confusion.
